# Expo and React Native - Context must be application context to avoid memory leak

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-modules

I'm trying to implement a Visa SDK through React Native's Native Modules. I'm currently using Expo 46. So far, the application is registered correctly, and I can view the 3 methods that are exposed within the app.

Unfortunately, whenever I call the `init()` method in my app, the application crashes, and this message appears.

> Context must be application context to avoid memory leak

Using `adb logcat` to further inspect the issue returns:

> Method addObserver must be called on the main thread

Leading me to the following line:

```java
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(new VisaInAppCoreApplicationObserver());
```

After some research, I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591942/1057052

Therefore, I tried running it like this:

```java
 getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(new VisaInAppCoreApplicationObserver());
                }
            });
```

But no luck.

Here's my code so far.

```java
// PushProvisioningModule.java
// adb logcat DEBUG-VISA:D *:S
package app.pana; // replace com.your-app-name with your app’s name

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.inAppCore.VisaInAppConfig;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.inAppCore.VisaInAppCore;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.inAppCore.VisaInAppCoreApplicationObserver;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.inAppCore.VisaInAppEnvironment;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPCardProvisioningRequest;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPCardProvisioningResponse;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPError;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPInitResponse;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPSupportedWallet;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPSupportedWalletCode;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPSupportedWalletRequest;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VPSupportedWalletResponse;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VisaPushProvisioningInterface;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VisaPushProvisioningInterfaceFactory;
import com.visa.mobileEnablement.pushProvisioning.VisaPushProvisioningListener;



import java.util.List;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

// adb logcat DEBUG-VISA:D *:S

/**
 * Page 32 Visa In-App Provisioning SDK Guide .pdf
 */
public class PushProvisioningModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    PushProvisioningModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface;
    private Callback successCallback;
    private Callback errorCallback;
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "PushProvisioningModule";
    }

    // Initialize
    @ReactMethod
    public void init(
            String appId,
            String environment,
            Callback errorCallback,
            Callback successCallback
    ) {
        Log.d("DEBUG-VISA", "Got here here");
        this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
        this.successCallback = successCallback;
        initializeSdk(appId, environment);
    }

    private void initializeSdk(String appId, String environment) {
        // VPInitRequest vpInitRequest = new VPInitRequest(environment, appId, null);
        runConfigure(environment, appId);
        VisaPushProvisioningListener listener = new VisaPushProvisioningListener() {
            // Initialization success result:
            @Override
            public void initializationSuccess(
                    VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    VPInitResponse vpInitResponse
            ) {
                String nonce = vpInitResponse.getSignedNonce();
                successCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpInitResponse));
            }

            // Initialization failure result:
            @Override
            public void initializationFailure(
                    @NotNull VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    @NotNull VPError vpError
            ) {
                errorCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpError));
            }

            // startCardProvisioning success result:
            @Override
            public void cardProvisioningSuccess(
                    @NotNull VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    @NotNull VPCardProvisioningResponse vpCardProvisioningResponse
            ) {
                Log.i(
                        "CARD PROVISIONING",
                        "Card Provisioning Success : " + vpCardProvisioningResponse
                );
                successCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpCardProvisioningResponse));
            }

            // startCardProvisioning failure result:
            @Override
            public void cardProvisioningFailure(
                    @NotNull VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    @NotNull VPError vpError
            ) {
                errorCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpError));
            }

            // getSupportedWallets success result:
            @Override
            public void supportedWalletSuccess(
                    @NotNull VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    @NotNull VPSupportedWalletResponse vpSupportedWalletResponse
            ) {
                List<VPSupportedWallet> vpSupportedWallets = vpSupportedWalletResponse.getWallets();
                successCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpSupportedWallets));
            }

            // getSupportedWallets failure result:
            @Override
            public void supportedWalletFailure(
                    @NotNull VisaPushProvisioningInterface visaPushProvisioningInterface,
                    @NotNull VPError vpError
            ) {
                errorCallback.invoke(gson.toJson(vpError));
            }
        };
        //VisaPushProvisioningInterfaceFactory.INSTANCE.createPushProvisioningInterface(getReactApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), vpInitRequest,
        visaPushProvisioningInterface =
                VisaPushProvisioningInterfaceFactory.INSTANCE.createPushProvisioningInterface(
                        listener,
                        null
                );
        visaPushProvisioningInterface.initialize();

        Log.d("DEBUG-VISA", "Initialization Successful");
    }

    private void runConfigure(String environment, String appId) {
        try {

            VisaInAppEnvironment configEnv = VisaInAppEnvironment.Production;
            //Log.d("DEBUG-VISA", "Configuration Environment", configEnv);
            VisaInAppConfig config = new VisaInAppConfig(configEnv, appId, null);
            ReactApplicationContext context = this.getReactApplicationContext();

            VisaInAppCore.Companion.configure(context, config);

            getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(new VisaInAppCoreApplicationObserver());
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG-VISA", "Exception thrown");
            Log.e("DEBUG-VISA", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // to declare delegate methods and initialize (described below)  }
    // Get eligible wallets
    @ReactMethod
    public void launchGetWallets(
            String encPayload,
            Callback errorCallback,
            Callback successCallback
    ) {
        Log.i("DEBUG-VISA", "Launching GET WALLETS");
        this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
        this.successCallback = successCallback;
        Log.i("DEBUG-VISA", "Launching GET WALLETS after callbacks");

        try {
            VPSupportedWalletRequest request = new VPSupportedWalletRequest(encPayload, null);
            visaPushProvisioningInterface.getSupportedWallets(
                    request
            );


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG-VISA", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Start card provisioning
    @ReactMethod
    public void launchStartCardProvisioning(
            String walletDescription,
            String walletCode,
            Callback errorCallback,
            Callback successCallback
    ) {
        this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
        this.successCallback = successCallback;
        visaPushProvisioningInterface.startCardProvisioning(
                getReactApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
                new VPCardProvisioningRequest(
                        VPSupportedWalletCode.valueOf(walletCode),
                        "PROVISIONING_REQUEST",
                        null
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
     /**
    * Visa SDK - START
    */
    //In-App Provisioning SDK
    implementation files('libs/VisaPushProvisioning-3.3.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/VisaInAppCore-3.3.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/TMXProfiling-6.1-67.aar')
    implementation files('libs/TMXProfilingConnections-6.1-67.aar')
    implementation files('libs/dexguard-runtime-9.2.12.aar')
    //Samsung Pay
    implementation files('libs/samsungpaysdk-2.6.00.jar')
    //Google Pay
    implementation files('libs/play-services-tapandpay-18.1.0.aar')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.0"
    //okhttp covers for okttp, okio dependency
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.9"
    implementation "net.minidev:json-smart:2.3"
    //For TrustDefender
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.6"
    implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13"
    //Nimbus
    implementation "com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:8.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.5.1"
    // If kotlin plugins are not added then below dependencies require to add to kotlin coroutines
    // used by SDK.
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
    //Analytics Database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"

    //Instant apps
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:18.0.0"

    /**
    * Visa SDK - END
    */
}
```

Note, that I was successfully able to use the code above inside a non-expo react-native application.

Comment: If you need further context, let me know.

Comment: @CyberMew Nope. This feature was never implemented